# Hadoop Restore from namenode and datanode files

Tags: file, hadoop, hdfs, restore, namenode

I have the datanode, namenode and secondary namenode folder (with all data or information inside) from a a different hadoop installation.

My question is, how can you see whats in there or add it to your local HDFS to see the data or information.

There can be a way to restore it or something, but i cant find any information about it.

The folder tree is like this:

For Namenode & SecondaryNamenode:

```
data/dfs/name
├── current
│ ├── VERSION
│ ├── edits_0000000000000000001-0000000000000000007
│ ├── edits_0000000000000000008-0000000000000000015
│ ├── edits_0000000000000000016-0000000000000000022
│ ├── edits_0000000000000000023-0000000000000000029
│ ├── edits_0000000000000000030-0000000000000000030
│ ├── edits_0000000000000000031-0000000000000000031
│ ├── edits_inprogress_0000000000000000032
│ ├── fsimage_0000000000000000030
│ ├── fsimage_0000000000000000030.md5
│ ├── fsimage_0000000000000000031
│ ├── fsimage_0000000000000000031.md5
│ └── seen_txid
```

And for Datanode:

```
data/dfs/data/
├── current
│ ├── BP-1079595417-192.168.2.45-1412613236271
│ │ ├── current
│ │ │ ├── VERSION
│ │ │ ├── finalized
│ │ │ │ └── subdir0
│ │ │ │ └── subdir1
│ │ │ │ ├── blk_1073741825
│ │ │ │ └── blk_1073741825_1001.meta
│ │ │ │── lazyPersist
│ │ │ └── rbw
│ │ ├── dncp_block_verification.log.curr
│ │ ├── dncp_block_verification.log.prev
│ │ └── tmp
│ └── VERSION
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard solution for copying data between different Hadoop clusters is to run the [DistCp](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html) command to execute a distributed copy of the desired files from source to destination.

Assuming that the other cluster is no longer running, and you only have these backup files, then it's possible to restore by copying the files that you have into the directories used by the new Hadoop cluster.  These locations will be specified in configuration properties in hdfs-site.xml: `dfs.namenode.name.dir` for the NameNode (your data/dfs/name directory) and `dfs.datanode.data.dir` for the DataNode (your data/dfs/data directory).

Please note that this likely will only work if you run the same version of Hadoop from the prior deployment.  Otherwise, there could be a compatibility problem.  If you attempt to run an older version, then the NameNode will fail to start.  If you attempt to run a newer version, then you may need to go through an upgrade process first by running `hdfs namenode -upgrade`.

One other option if you just need to look at the file system metadata is to use the [Offline Image Viewer](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#oiv) and [Offline Edits Viewer](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#oev) commands.  These commands can decode and browse the fsimage and edits files respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer is better than i expected to receive. I see that you are an expert in Hadoop, thank you for the answer. Although i could not execute the ./hdfs oiv -i $HADOOP_HOME/namenode/current/fsimage -o fsimage.txt command properly, maybe i need to search more about the command. Kind regards